# Как передать название файла по сокету?

Tags: java, сокет

Приложение будет передавать множество файлов, и мне важно, что бы они были переданы с названиями. Для этого нужно отправлять каждый раз сообщение с названием файла или это как то можно сделать иначе?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Первым байтом отправляете длину имени файла, следующие 4 байта - длина файла, следом байты имени файла, а потом байты самого файла. Или, чтобы не заморачиваться с конвертацией данных, можно поля чуточку расширить:

**Server.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    private static int PORT = 2121;
    private static String FOLDER = "./files";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File sourceDir = new File(FOLDER);

        try (ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
            while (true) {
                try (Socket socket = listener.accept();
                     OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream()) {
                    for (String fileName : sourceDir.list()) {
                        // Преобразовываем строку, содержащую имя файла,
                        // в массив байт
                        byte[] name = fileName.getBytes("utf-8");
                        // Отправляем длину этого массива
                        out.write(name.length);
                        // Отправляем байты имени
                        out.write(name);

                        File file = new File(FOLDER + "/" + fileName);

                        // Получаем размер файла
                        long fileSize = file.length();
                        // Конвертируем его в массив байт
                        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
                        buf.putLong(fileSize);
                        // И отправляем
                        out.write(buf.array());

                        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                            // Читаем файл блоками по килобайту
                            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                            int read;
                            while ((read = in.read(data)) != -1) {
                                // И отправляем в сокет
                                out.write(data);
                            }
                        }
                        catch(IOException exc) {
                            exc.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(IOException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    private static int PORT = 2121;
    private static String HOST = "localhost";
    private static String FOLDER = "./files";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Socket s = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
             InputStream in = s.getInputStream()) {

            // Читаем размер имени
            int nameSize;
            while((nameSize = in.read()) != -1) {
                // Читаем само имя
                byte[] name = new byte[nameSize + 1];
                in.read(name, 0, nameSize);
                // Преобразовываем обратно в строку
                String fileName = new String(name, "utf-8").trim();
                System.out.println(fileName);

                File file = new File(FOLDER + "/" + fileName);
                try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                    // Читаем размер файл
                    byte[] fileSizeBuf = new byte[8];
                    in.read(fileSizeBuf, 0, 8);
                    // Преобразовываем в long
                    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
                    buf.put(fileSizeBuf);
                    buf.flip();
                    long fileSize = buf.getLong();

                    // Читаем содержимое файла блоками по килобайту
                    int read = 0;
                    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                    while (read < fileSize) {
                        read += in.read(data);
                        // И пишем в файл
                        out.write(data);
                    }
                }
                catch(IOException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Добрый день, подскажите, чем можно заменить эту строку.for (String fileName : sourceDir.list()). При запуске клиента и сервера на стороне сервера появляется

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
at Server.main(Server.java:2

Часть строки подсвечивается желтым,и idea предлагает заменить ее на Objects.requireNonNull(sourceDir.list()) Но результат тот же, подскажите чем можно заменить

Comment: Надо не заменять, а разобраться, что делает эта строка и почему выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Как я понимаю в этой строке мы создаем цикл forech после создаем резервную стринговую переменную в которую поступают строки из файла, файл при этом мы пытаемся разбить на массив строк

Comment: А ошибка может возникнуть в этой строке если есть проблема с файлом. Спасибо, попробую поискать =)

Answer (score 4):

Есть несколько подходов к решению Вашей проблемы:

1. Сериализация. Использовать встроенную сериализацию ([Java Serialization API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html)), либо [одну из популярных библиотек](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo). То есть вы сериализуете объект, передаете и десериализуете его на приемной стороне.
2. Использовать свой протокол обмена данных. Например, после установления соединения, клиент передает имя файла, получает подтверждение от сервера, затем передает содержимое файла и снова получает подтверждение о получении файла.
3. Посылать имя файла и его содержимое одним запросом, тогда необходимо организовывать формат передачи данных, как уже было описано [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/717301/#717306)